# Careers: two "are you actively looking" emails is one too many

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I received this email question on December 26th and again today.

> You’re currently marked as actively looking for a job. Is this still
>   correct? If you are actively looking for a job, we’ll prioritize your
>   CV and work hard to get you the maximum possible matches with
>   companies as quickly as possible. If you're not actively looking, you
>   can still mark your CV open, but not actively looking and we'll send
>   you fewer, more selective matches

As a contractor I am actively looking for work every day.  I appreciate that Careers is still a beta but two emails in two weeks is one too many.

Other job sites will check on my status every three or six months which is fine.

Is this a bug or a feature?  If it's a feature please allow the user to set the period for checking in from a range of values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. The emails you received were introduced as part of a set of changes aimed at improving the accuracy of the job search status field in our CV database. We had found that many CVs were no longer Active, which diluted the value of that field for other CVs and job seekers.

The system sends a reminder email 3 weeks after you set your status to Actively Looking. If, 3 weeks *after that*, you haven't re-affirmed your Active status (or applied for a job), the system will downgrade your status to Passively Looking and send you an email notification. So you actually have 6 weeks during which you can remain Active without having to take any action. Does this information alleviate your concerns at all?

That said, your case is certainly legit - contractors are always looking. We'd like to get more feedback before making changes to accommodate this use case, but some things under consideration are:

- the reminder email could be sent at 5 weeks, and the downgrade occur 1 week later
- the downgrade clock can be reset if you perform some job searches or view jobs
- the clock for job seekers who indicate interest in contract jobs on their CV can be longer than for those who don't
- the downgrade clock could simply be extended - but this is a balancing act and our hunch is that 3 - 6 months would be too long.

That's ordered roughly by increasing cost - do you feel any of those would address your concerns?

Comment: the most acceptable to me is "the clock for job seekers who indicate interest in contract jobs on their CV can be longer than for those who don't". However there are subtle nuances to looking for work.  Have a job offer a thousand miles from where I live?  Not really interested.  Have a low paying job down the street from where I live? Not really interested. The converse is also true: the right combinations of location, pay and type of work will make me very interested very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. We'll keep this in mind as we prioritize areas for improvement.

Comment: Hi to @G-Wiz still getting these emails every three weeks.